# How to easily share files/directories remotely under Windows?

Tags: windows

I am looking for an as-easy-as-possible solution to share files and directories using Windows XP and Windows 7.

Requirements:

- direct connection, no upload to 3rd party servers (e.g. Dropbox)
- easy set-up, suited for technophobes. E.g. setting up an FTP server or likewise is not an option
- support for dynamic IPs
- remote connection via internet

Nice to have:

- encrypted transfer

So far, I have not been able to find an easy solution for this. Or is there maybe a good solution built into Windows itself, which I have not found?
From the usability point-of-view, a solution similar to Crossloop would be great, i.e. start a piece of software, exchange an alphanumeric code and here you go.

Best regards in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer to yoru revised question is to use Remote Desktop. You will need to open port 3389 on the remote computer's firewall, or firewalls if there is both a hardware and software firewall in the way.

You will also need some kind of DNS, or dynmanic DNS setup to help you resolve it if the remote IP is going to change. You can get a free Dynamic DNS account here:

http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/

As far as how to transfer files, you can do this:

[image]

Here is how it looks on the remote computer (note the bottom "drive".

[image]

Comment: P.S. It is encrypted.

Comment: Wow... that sounds fairly simple indeed. I did not know that there was such an easy way to serve a remote desktop connection. Great! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help, and thank you for marking the answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

On one or both machines, do the following:

Right click the folder you want to share, and share it. Set the permissions for everyone to Full (since it is a home network, this is pretty safe). You will also need to assign the folder permissions for everyone.

From the other computer you can now browse to the sharing computer, double click it, and see the share. You can then right-click the share, and do "Map network drive" if you want to assign it a letter. Another easy way to use the share is simply to run the command `net use x: \\computername\share` from a command line.

This is how I shared Temp on Windows 7 Ultimate (it may vary slightly with the Home editions).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer... No, it is not a home network - it is supposed to be a remote connection. Sorry if that was not clear in the question. I'll add this to the list of requirements, too.

Comment: Ahh, that is a whole new story. I will complete the screen shots for others, then try to post a new answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought having "remotely" in the headline and dynamic IPs in the reqs would be sufficient, but I see it was a bit misleading. Thanks for your excellent answers, though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remotely share files as well regardless of the ip address, you can use Logmein Hamachi which is a great and free for noncommercial use VPN program. It establishes outgoing connections and will then link your two computers together. Whether your on the same network or remotely, it will act like the two computers are sitting right next to each other. Each computer will be given a second ip address that you can use to browse the shares, rdp, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Logmein Hamachi. I did not know this piece of software. I'll have to try this at home, but it seems to be even easier (technophobe-safe :)) to use than the RDC. I will keep you updated about the results :)

Comment: One of it's coolest features other than web access to manage your networks is the ability to create different types of networks. On my server, I have a hub network. All members of that network can only see the server and not each other. Then I have a mesh network where all of my personal computers can see each other.

Comment: I run a personal cloud at home and have a mine craft server set up with hamachi. I don't want other members to see each others computer for security reasons so I make them all clients and the server the node. It's pretty cool. I haven't found a VPN software that is this flexible and easy to maintain.